# Sub-branching in ClearCase?

Tags: unix, clearcase

When I want to use a branch in CC, I usually put something like this in the config spec:

```
element * .../first_branch/LATEST
element * .../Main/LATEST -mkbranch first_branch
element * ../Main/LATEST
```

Now, I want to create a branch that is a sub-branch of the first one. Let's say it's called `second_branch` (I'm creative today). How would that config spec look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
element * .../second_branch/LATEST
element * .../first_branch/LATEST -mkbranch second_branch
element * .../Main/LATEST -mkbranch first_branch
element * ../Main/LATEST
```

Your view will now look at the latest version on second_branch, or, if it doesn't exist, the latest version on first_branch, or, if it doesn't exist there, the latest version on the main branch. Upon checking out a file, a new version element will be created on respectively second_branch and first_branch as necessarily.

I don't have access to a ClearCase instance right now, so I can't double check your last two lines, but I think that perhaps you meant this instead?

```
element * .../second_branch/LATEST
element * .../first_branch/LATEST -mkbranch second_branch
element * /Main/LATEST -mkbranch first_branch
```

Answer (score 5):

To add to Kim's answer, I much prefer starting a branch from a label than the `LATEST` versions selected by a branch.
That way, I know what '`second_branch`' stands from and where it comes from.
(coming from the `LATEST` of another branch means it comes from a moving point which represents something different as time goes by)

```
element * .../second_branch/LATEST
element * A_LABEL -mkbranch second_branch
element * .../first_branch/LATEST
element * .../Main/LATEST -mkbranch first_branch
element * ../Main/LATEST
```

If you set `A_LABEL` on a view configured to be:

- at the `LATEST` of '`first_branch`'
- at a 'stable' state

,then you can branch from a known point.