# Copy ClearCase element with its history

Tags: clearcase

Is it possible to copy a clearcase element with its full history of merges/versions/labels and other meta data? I have tried `clearfsimport` but it seams it only copies one version not the full element history.

Answer (score 1):

clearsimport won't copy history, only import and create *one* version in a VOB.

Saving everything is generally at the VOB level (like "[Moving VOBs](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/c_mvvob.htm)").
Moving one element from one vob to another is called [relocate](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_relocate.htm).

But *copying* doesn't seen to exist.
The easiest way is to manage that element in a branch, which allows you to isolate changes from the main branch, while working on the *same* element.

---

Note: [Brian Cowan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4223401/brian-cowan) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068404/copy-clearcase-element-with-its-history/13069789?noredirect=1#comment105687058_13069789):

> Relocate with `-update` will clone elements from one location to another without deleting them from the source VOB.
>   I would not recommend this if both the source and destination VOBs are to be used in the same audited builds as it WILL confuse build audits

Comment: I need to copy an element for the purpose of testing scripts that automaticaly handel branch outs and such. The reson I need to copy the entier history is I have scripts that traverse trees and do different opperations on version bubbles. When testing this it alters the history and I need to reset it. How can I do this?

Comment: @PabloKarlsson Just create a snapshot view and run your test script on it.

Comment: What is a snapshot view? How can I create it and how do I remove checkouts and checkins?

Comment: @PabloKarlsson are your testing script generate those checkouts? For creating a snapshot view, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207409/proper-cleartool-mkview-for-clearcase-snapshot-view-creation/1207516#1207516 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703648/get-the-error-when-creating-the-view-cleartool-mkview-tag-view-name-view-nam/8704153#8704153.

Comment: @PabloKarlsson What version of ClearCase are you using? What brand? Base ClearCase, ClearCase with UCM streams? CCRC (remote client)?

Comment: Hmm that's a tricky question I use a special implementation for Ericsson I think I am not the owner of the vobs. So im not quite sure.

Comment: @PabloKarlsson do you have access to the ClearCase Explorer, or to `cleartool`?

Comment: What I would like to do is create some type of temporary view or folder where I can rage havoc destroy everything and then recreate the hole lot from scratch. So I can create automatic tests for checking in checking out and more.

Comment: Im actualy creating java bindings to cleartool atm thats why I need the tests.

Comment: @PabloKarlsson the surest way is to create a snapshot view with mkbranch rule in order to make sure that any checkout required by your scripts are done in their own branch. See as an example of "sub-branching": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635607/sub-branching-in-clearcase/4635864#4635864

Comment: I think maby its not possible then becuse I know how to branch and checkout the problem I face here is that im actualy recording the clearcase treastructure in java. I have the branches the version the merge arrows and so on. What I want to do Is make sure these things are done acuratley So I need to test them. It's how ever difficult becuse I need the same environment evry time I test and during the tests I modify the clearcase tree. So I need a way to reset it to its original states preferably without branches since branch creation is an event that I might like to test.

Comment: @PabloKarlsson unless you can duplicate a Vob (which "Moving a Vob" does to a certain extent) and register it under another tag in your ClearCase registry, you cannot do *exactly* what you are after, mainly because those tests *modify* the Vob elements.

Comment: Ok I have tried contacting my superiors to get access to a vob of my own. Hope fully this vill solve the issue. Thnaks for all the help.

Comment: @VonC Relocate with -update will clone elements from one location to another without deleting them from the source VOB. I would not recommend this if both the source and destination VOBs are to be used in the same audited builds as it WILL confuse build audits.

Comment: @BrianCowan Thank you for your comment. I have included it in the answer for more visibility. I don't recall having ever used build audit though.